# Folder list php

Tags: php, list, file, directory

I want to list the folder names in the list there's a file foldername Show. Already has a problem, please do a test. Another code would be ok.

```
<?php
function getFileList($folderName, $fileType = "")
{
    if (substr($folderName, strlen($folderName) - 1) != "/") {
        $folderName .= '/';
    }

    foreach (glob($folderName . '*' . $fileType) as $filename) {
        if (is_dir($filename)) {
            $type = 'folder';
        } else {
            $type = 'file';
        }
        echo  str_replace($folderName, '', $filename .'<br/>');
    }
}

// call the function
getFileList('foldername'); // list all files



?>

<select class="form" name="userlevel" size="1">
<option value="<?php getFileList('themes'); ?>">فولدر 1</option>
<option value="<?php getFileList('themes'); ?>">فولدر 2</option>
<option value="<?php getFileList('themes'); ?>">فولدر 3</option>
</select>
```

No file. folder

Comment: Ask your question explicitly. What output you need?

Comment: try using absolute path of the directory